# I want to use Bootstrap Modal buttons to return results on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

My aim is to override the jquery `confirm()` function with  `function

```
confirm(message){
        //There is a modal opened already
        $('#confirm').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'}); //Show second modal on top of the first modal
        $('#confirm').find('.modal-title').html(message);
                $('.confirm').on('click',function(){ //on Confirm button click of the second modal
                        $('#confirm').removeClass('fade').modal('hide');//Hide the Second modal
                        $('.page-body').addClass('modal-open'); // Addig back modal-open class to body element to prevent modal conflict
                        callback(); //some suggested this but it doesnt work
                        return true; //I want to return this to the function called this function but i get no results
                });
                $('.cancel').on('click',function(){
                        $('#confirm').removeClass('fade').modal('hide');
                        $('.page-body').addClass('modal-open'); 
                        callback(); 
                        return false; 
                });

            $('.close').on('click',function(){
                    $('#confirm').removeClass('fade').modal('hide');
                    $('.page-body').addClass('modal-open'); 
                    callback(); 
                    return 'cancel';
            });
}`  I am not getting any results when I call the function
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `jQuery` doesn't have a `confirm()` function, so you're either using the browser's built-in function or some plugin...
2. You're not returning anything from your custom `confirm` function. You're defining event handlers that may eventually return values, but they won't return anything until they're called.

It's hard to figure out what this function should be doing. Can you summarize the logic in English?

**Here's what it looks like your code is doing right now:**

When the user calls the built-in `confirm` function,

1. Show a modal dialog
2. Set its title to the `message` parameter
3. Do nothing right now, but attach an `onclick` event handler to the `confirm` class.
4. Do nothing right now, but attach an `onclick` event handler to the `cancel` class.
5. Do nothing right now, but attach an `onclick` event handler to the `close` class.

It's too late to do anything useful with those event handlers at that point, and you'll never see their return values.

If you post your HTML and say *step-by-step, in detail* what order you want events to happen in, people can help. But otherwise I'm not sure how.

Comment: Okay, I thought its Jquery function Thanks.

Comment: For example, I want to delete something from the server but I dont want to delete without confirming so to confirm, i want to call this custom function `confirm()` and the when a user click Confirm button, the function must return `true`, when they click Cancel return `false` and when the click just close return `close` or `false` and then the code continue executing

Comment: Okay, but I can't tell what your approach is without having you step me through all the blocks of code in your function. But let's take a different approach: I don't think you want to override the browser's `confirm` function at all. I think you want to add an event handler to the Confirm button that will ask the user if they're sure.

Comment: The `confirm()` function does work without the one i put above. You can call the function like this `confirm('The message you want to display on the dialogue')` and then a dialogue will pop with your message, when you click OK, it return's `true` and when you click CANCEL it return's `false` so some said to override it, create a function `confirm()` and do your own code. but I want to add event handler indeed. I want to user the bootsrap dialogue instead of the built in

Comment: Absolutely, there is a `confirm` function that belongs to the `Window` object, and when it's called it brings up a dialog box. But it sounds like you don't want to bring up the default dialog box, you want to display a custom modal box with the choice to Confirm or Cancel. Is that right?